# Right maven plugin for JBoss 7.x

Tags: java, maven, jboss, maven-plugin, jboss7.x

I would like to be able to control the following simple workflow with it:

**start AS -> deploy/undeploy app -> stop AS**

AFAIK there are at least 3 maven plugins promising to facilitate JBoss management and app deployment. I have no experience with any of them and I have found no resources comparing them or giving clear advice on which one to use for what.

the [jboss-maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/jboss/) on the official maven site,
the [jboss-as-maven plugin](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin) on github, and 
the [cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) on codehaus.

The **jboss-maven plugin** seems outdated as it is found within the maven1 thread. I have some doubts that it will work with JBoss 7

The **jboss-as-maven** plugin seems to support deployment and undeployment only, not the startup and shutdown. This is the plugin used by the JBoss 7 examples, but it obviosly misses the jboss administration targets

I'm not sure about the **cargo** plugin. I am not familiar with cargo API, but the feature list seems right and JBoss 7.x is supported.

Any practical advice/ best practices welcome.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [Maven Cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) without any problems at all. Both JBoss 7.0 and 7.1 are responding correctly. So I would go that road.

I'm also using Cargo API within my JUnit tests, ant it's quite straightforward as well. It wasn't hard to use it at all. Good starting points are:

- [Integrating Cargo with JUnit](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Functional+testing).
- [List of articles about Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Articles).
- [Cargo sources](https://fisheye.codehaus.org/viewrep/cargo) - take look at `extensions/trunk/ant` - it's a good way to start learning how to integrate Cargo into one's app.

Comment: thanks Lukasz, I'll try it out (may take some time) and accept once I have come to terms with it. Why do you prefer it over the other two plugins?

Comment: The big (biggest) advantage of Cargo comes from development process - it exists. Every month there are bug fixes, new commits and once a new version of any container comes out, the implementation in Cargo comes right after it - week or two at most. For me that's the winner.

Answer (score 1):

Currently what you're referring to as the [`jboss-as-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin) is the official plugin. This is the plugin that is being maintained and updated. It currently does not contain a way to start or stop the server, but feel free to file a [feature request](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin/issues).

One advantage of the [`jboss-as-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin) is you will soon, hopefully today, be able to deploy to both domain and standalone servers. You can also [deploy resources](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html#Deploying_other_artifacts) such as data sources and [add resource](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/add-resource-example.html).

There are also plans to be able to execute arbitrary commands that would work just like CLI.

Comment: thanks, James. I actually felt free and filed an issue WRT the start/stop targets. Really curious about it.

Comment: @kostja Cool. We'll see what we can do then :-)